# Android - Threads, Runnable and concurrent data access

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

While working on an Android app I stumbled upon something and wanted to get your opinion/help on the subject.

So, basically, I am creating several `Runnable`s that run in different threads. All these `Runnable`s call a method `ApplyContrast(...)` from the class `SomeClass` that runs these `Runnable`s (more or less simultaneously).
This `ApplyContrast(...)` method accesses and modifies an `int[]` of the same class `SomeClass`.

So I was wondering if this was/could be a problem ? 
I am asking this because I don't get the expected result when I run this on more than 1 thread.

P.S: Even though there is concurrent access to the `int[]` the threads are not accessing the same part of the array (or are not supposed to do it :P)

Any help is welcome. If you need more information just ask.

```
public class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass {

    // The number of threads that will be used to do the data processing
    private static int mNumberOfThreadsToCreate = 10;

    private int mPixelArrayLength;

    private int mRunningThreadCount;

    public SomeClass(AnotherClass callback, int[] pixels, int length) {
        super(callback, pixels);

        mPixelArrayLength = length;
        mRunningThreadCount = mNumberOfThreadsToCreate;
    }

    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {    
                final int lenByChunk = mPixelArrayLength / mNumberOfThreadsToCreate;
                for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfThreadsToCreate; ++i) {
                    int len = lenByChunk;
                    if (i == (mNumberOfThreadsToCreate - 1))
                        len += (mPixelArrayLength - mNumberOfThreadsToCreate * lenByChunk);
                    applyToChunk(mPixels, i * lenByChunk, len, 128);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void applyToChunk(final int[] pixels, final int offset, final int len, final int contrastLevel) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                applyContrast(pixels, offset, len, contrastLevel);    
                --mRunningThreadCount;    
                onFinish();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    //set value in range 0 - 255
    private int keepInRange(int colorValue) {
        if (colorValue < 0)
            colorValue = 0;
        else if (colorValue > 255)
            colorValue = 255;

        return colorValue;
    }

    /**
     * contrastLevel should be in <-128, 128> range
     */
    private void applyContrast(int[] pixels, int offset, int pixelsLen, int contrastLevel) {
        double correctionFactor = 259.047619047619;
        double factor = (correctionFactor * (contrastLevel + 255)) / (255 * (correctionFactor - contrastLevel));

        for(int i = offset; i < pixelsLen; ++i) {

            int red = keepInRange((int)(factor * (Color.red(pixels[i]) - 128) + 128));
            int green = keepInRange((int)(factor * (Color.green(pixels[i]) - 128) + 128));
            int blue = keepInRange((int)(factor * (Color.blue(pixels[i]) - 128) + 128));
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixels[i]);
            pixels[i] = Color.argb(alpha, blue, green, red);//invert sequence here.
        }
    }

    private void onFinish() {
        // Shouldn't be < 0 or there is a really serious problem ...
        if (mRunningThreadCount <= 0 && super.mCallback != null) {
            super.mCallback.onFinish(super.mPixels);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #1:**

To add a bit more information about what the (wrong) result is:

As I said above, I don't get the expected result whenever I do the data processing in several threads.
When the data processing is done in multiple threads **only** the data processed in the first thread (that was run) is correct.

Here are some pictures to show the original image, the expected result and the actual resulting image I get when multithreading:

(Don't mind the blue parts on top and on the bottom of the images)

**Original image:**
[image]

**Expected resulting image:**
[image]

**Actual resulting image:**
[image]

You can see that in the last image we have "2 parts". The 1st part (at the top) is the one processed by the 1st thread (this is done correctly) and the 2nd (at the bottom) processed by all the remaining threads (this is what's wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok.

The array `pixels` (probably aliased as `mPixels`) is accessed from more than one thread.  That would make it incorrect.

It appears, though, that you are chunking access to the array so that each thread accesses only its own chunk.  As long as multiple threads never access the same spot in the array, the code is correct.

I gotta say, though, that it is wildly confusing.  I would say that the variable `len` is misnamed.  Certainly, the concurrency correctness is really hard to determine.  I believe that it could be written more clearly and that, with something so error-prone, it would be well worth doing so.

Comment: It is true that the `len` variable is misnamed..I've checked it's content and there is nothing wrong there.

I've updated my post. Please take a look if you have the time.